# How to display a table dynamically in Thymleaf with Java?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, nested-loops

How can I display a table in HTML code using Thymleaf and Java?

Backend: (I created a HTML Template with TemplateEngine)

```
private Map<String, Object> createAdditionalContext() {

  Map<String, Object> additionalContext = new HashMap<>();

  ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<Integer> columns = new ArrayList<>();

  // Number of columns and rows in the table
  int numColumns = 10;
  int numRows = 1;


 for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
     rows.add(i);

     for (int j = 1; j <= 25; j++) {
         columns.add(j);

         // FIXME
         if (j % 5 == 0) {
             rows.add(i);
             break;
         }
     }
 }

 additionalContext.put("rows", rows);
 additionalContext.put("columns", columns);

 return additionalContext;
}
```

Frontend:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr th:each="row: ${rows}">
         <td th:each="col: ${columns}" th:text="${col}"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Output now:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

Output should be:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the 2 blocks to one. After that you just have to copy the line and so you have 2 blocks next to each other.

Backend:

```
private Map<String, Object> createAdditionalContext() {
   Map<String, Object> additionalContext = new HashMap<>();

   int[][] array = new int[5][5];
   int number = 1;

   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
           array[i][j] = number;
           number++;
       }
   }

   additionalContext.put("array", array);

   return additionalContext;
}
```

Frontend:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr th:each="row : ${array}">
        <td th:each="element : ${row}" th:text="${element}"></td>
        <td th:each="element : ${row}" th:text="${element}"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```